# Excel 2013 Decimal Point converts into Comma in another PC

Tags: excel, decimal

I am having problems recently with Excel 2013.I want decimal point instead of comma. 
I have in the cell written 5.75. I send the Excel file via email and the receiver gets 5,75. But if the receiver send it to me like this with comma, I get in my excel shown 5.75. Where can the Problem be?

P.S I have checked in Advanced, Use System separator.

Comment: That is due to the locale of excel. If the computer where it is used has USA as region/language and in another PC it has Gemany, you will get the same effect. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul) you can see more about it

Answer (score 0):

This is "by design" Excel uses the Windows Locale settings asa set in Windows Control panel, Reion and language to decide what decimal and thousands separators to use.

These can be overridden in Excel's options. This however is an Excel-wide setting (not a per-workbook setting) so I would not advise to change it, otherwise you will confuse your users enormously.